# Weird output after assign new char

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, char

**This is my code [NOTE: not the full code, but only these cause problem]**

```
#define RNC 3
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    char *labyrinth[RNC + 2] = {
        "00000",
        "01100",
        "00101",
        "01111",
        "00101",
    };

    char *markedLabyrinth[RNC + 2] = {
        "00000",
        "00000",
        "00000",
        "00000",
        "00000",
    };

    printf("Test = %s\n", markedLabyrinth[1]);
    printf("Please specific where is the exit point Ex. [ 3 5 ] : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &K, &L);

    int i, row, column;
    markedLabyrinth[1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    markedLabyrinth[1][2] = '1';
    printf("Test After = %s\n", markedLabyrinth[1]);
}
```

.

**And this is the output from my compiler**

```
Test = 00000
Please specific where is the exit point Ex. [ 3 5 ] : 3 4 // this is my input, [ignore it ^^]
Test After = @q1
```

and as you can see i tried to assign just the **markLabyrinth[1][2] to = '1'** and the output should be

```
Test After = 00100
```

but it gives me

```
Test After = @q1
```

Please take a look at this code for me please,**Thank you**

Comment: @user3121023 can you give me some proposed fix, please? thank you

Comment: @user3121023 you mean I have to malloc all the markedLabyrinth[0-4] and strcpy to assign the char to the default value [00000], instead of assign in the { ... } right?

Comment: @user3121023 oh thank you, i tried and it's seem to be work ;D +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line where you allocate the new string you have not initialized it.  Whenever you allocate it is good practice to initialize the storage to a known value.  For example,

`markedLabyrinth[1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);`

To

`markedLabyrinth[1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);`
`strcpy(markedLabyrinth[1], "00000");`

Note though that you have effectively dereferenced the original value of the string.  In your simple case it is a literal so it doesn’t matter.  Should you be executing this code a second time you would be abandoning the reference to the previous string and would create a memory leak.  In that case, you should use `free()` the previous reference to avoid other issues with memory allocation.

Comment: It's fixed now ^^ , Thank you sir, for the proposed fix and the additional info;D